# How to use recursion to determine if characters are in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, recursion

Right now I'm trying to use recursion of a function with two parameters to find whether or not the second is included in the first. As an example:

```
def recurseString(full, inclusive):
    ...............
```

With this I would take something along the lines of:

```
recurseString('jack','kcj')
```

and this would return "True" whereas something like:

```
recurseString('stan','xun')
```

would return "False"

I'm rather new to python so this is rather confusing. Any ideas on how to go about this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to use recursion for this?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "included by"? You mean each character in `inclusive` is also in `full`, and repeated characters have to be matched repeatedly? Or something different?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return True even if there are duplicate *letters* in `inclusive` but but only one in `full`:

```
def recurseString(full, inclusive):
    if not inclusive:
        return True
    return inclusive[0] in full and recurseString(full, inclusive[1:])

>>> print recurseString('jack','kkkcccjjj')
True
```

The following requires `full` to contain the same number of *duplicate* letters - if `inclusive` has three k's `full` must have three k's:

```
def recurseString(full, inclusive, first_call = True):
    # first time through, sort the arguments to make the algorithm easier
    if first_call:
        full, inclusive = map(sorted, (full, inclusive))
        first_call = False
    # two base cases, inclusive has been exhausted
    if not inclusive:
        return True
    try:
        index = full.index(inclusive[0])
    except ValueError:
        # and (2nd base case) first item of inclusive is not in full
        return False
    return recurseString(full[index+1:], inclusive[1:], first_call)


>>> print recurseString('jack','kkkcccjjj')
False
>>> print recurseString('jckackjkjc','kkkcccjjj')
True
>>>
```

Using the `index` method seemed like *cheating* -

```
def foo(full, inclusive, first_call = True):
    if first_call:
        full, inclusive = map(sorted, (full, inclusive))
    if not full and inclusive:
        return False
    if not inclusive:
        return True
    if inclusive[0] == full[0]:
        inclusive = inclusive[1:]
    return foo(full[1:], inclusive, False)


assert not foo('','kkkcccjjj')
assert not  foo('sun','xun')
assert not  foo('jack','kkkcccjjj')
assert foo('s', 's')
assert foo('jckackjkjc','kkkcccjjj')
assert foo('','')
assert foo('a','')
```

Comment: The first function is a recursive process.  The second function is a recursive procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you are looking for ...

```
In [51]: def recurseString(a,b):
   ....:     if b == '': return True
   ....:     else:
   ....:         if len(b) == 1: return b in a
   ....:         else: return (b[0] in a) and recurseString(a, b[1:])
   ....:

In [52]: recurseString('jack', 'kjc')
Out[52]: True

In [53]: recurseString('stan', 'xun')
Out[53]: False
```

However, there is no need for recursion. This is much better solved using `all` like so:

```
In [57]: all( [s in 'jack'  for s in 'kjc'] )
Out[57]: True
```

which is far more Pythonic.

It is also possible to use `reduce` which is more *functional* but much less readable, since Python has much better ways of handling this.

```
In [60]: reduce(lambda x,y: (x and (y in 'jack'))  , 'kjc', True)
Out[60]: True
```

Finally, this wouldn't be complete without using the `set` notation:

```
In [65]: (set('kjc') - set('jack')) == set()
Out[65]: True
```

So as you can see, the recursive version is the least suitable for this problem!

Comment: You can leave out the `[]` in the call to `all()` to prevent creating an extra list object

Comment: Thanks Jason. I tried that first. For some reason, it creates a generator object: `In [55]: print all( s in 'jack'  for s in 'kjc' )
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x085B0F80>`. Not sure why ...

Comment: That's odd. I ran it in python 2 & 3 to be sure and it Worked For Me(tm). That should be the output without the `all()`

Comment: you don't print it, it is a generator expression so printing it will print the object.

Comment: That was what I copied form iPython. Not sure if something is wrong on this computer. When I try it in my home computer, it generally works. That's the reason I added a `print` statement, hoping that the print would force the generator to evaluate and print the result. No use :(. I even tried `
In [54]: all( s in 'jack'  for s in 'kjc' )
Out[54]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x05D33350>`

Comment: `In [28]: all( s in 'jack' for s in 'kjc' )
Out[28]: True` print sometimes works for me, sometimes I get <generator object <genexpr>  but usually without print always works

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham. It sucks when it works in everyone else's computer and not on mine. No need to rub it in :). I have already conceded that it is *supposed to work*.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I actually like your recursive implementation better than mine. +1 for that. I was hoping that this one could end up being tail-recursive, but I doubt it!

Comment: lol, what version of python are you using, it is interesting that your output is different?

Comment: Am using `Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]`. This one should be ok with generators. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: You can simply `return len(set('kjc') - set('jack'))`

Comment: `print` doesn't "force the generator to evaluate". Only iterating over it will do that. But `all` should never return a generator. Is it possible that you're defining a different function named `all` in your IPython startup files? Maybe you've got a magic %all function, and you've got the auto-magic-no-%-needed flag (which I forget the name of) enabled?

Answer (score 1):

To think about any problem recursively, you have to break it into a base case (or sometimes multiple base cases), and a recursive case (or sometimes multiple recursive cases).

I'm going to assume that "included by" means "each character in `inclusive` is also in `full`, and in fact each character that appears in `inclusive` N times is also in `full` at least N times".

So, if `inclusive` is empty, it's vacuously True.

But if the `full` is empty and `inclusive` is not, it's False.

Otherwise, if the first character of `full` is in inclusive, it's true iff `full[1:]` contains `inclusive` minus that character.

Otherwise, it's true iff `full[1:]` contains `inclusive`.

Now you just have to translate that to code.

If you don't need to handle repeated characters, you can simplify this by just testing `inclusive[0]` and recursing on `inclusive[1:]`, instead of recursing on `full[1:]`.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

```
def recurseString(str1,str2):
    if str2 == "": #  str2 == "" all str2 letters are in str1
        return True
    elif str2[0] in str1:
        return recurseString(str1, str2[1:]) # move to next letter in str2
    return False # if we get here we have found a letter that is not in str1

In [22]: recurseString('stan','xun')
Out[22]: False

In [23]: recurseString('jack','kcj')
Out[23]: True
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is right or not; it depends on whether `recurseString('jack', 'kcjj')` should be true or false, which the OP hasn't told us…

Comment: Also, the `str1 == str2` check isn't helping anything; `'spam' == 'maps'` isn't true, but you've reached "both strings are equal" anyway. You could compare `sorted` (if duplicates count) or `set` (if they don't), but that seems to be over-complicating things.

Comment: @abarnert if str1 is spam and str2 is spam why would you go any further? I am pretty sure the code is correct or else the OP will be a long time figuring out how to recursively solve a more complicated version

Comment: If `str1` is `'spam'` and `str2` is `'maps'` why would you go any further? It's an extra optimization that probably isn't needed, so why add it?

Comment: @abarnert, fair enough  I removed it but having two identical words is slightly different to two words with the same letters.

Comment: love to know what the downvote was for

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you  need recursive to implement it, it's difficult to read and understand.

MY GOD, It's a challenge for me to read my code.

```
def recurseSring(full, inclusive):
    for i in range(len(full)):
        for j in range(len(inclusive)):
            if full[i] == inclusive[j]:
                if recurseSring(full[i + 1:], inclusive[j + 1:]):
                    return True
            if full[i] == inclusive[j] and len(inclusive) == 1:
                return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if recurseSring('lifenglifeng001', 'lifeng'):
        print('OK, equal')
    else:
        print('NOT equal')
```

Answer (score 0):

Short but sweet.

```
def recurseString(full, incl):
    return incl[:1] in full and (incl[:1] == '' or recurseString(full, incl[1:]))
```

The 'and' ensures both parts of the expression are true.

The first part - takes the first character of inclusive and searches for it in the full string:

```
incl[:1] in full     #returns '' if incl is ''
```

The second part - this is true if you search with a null string (incl), have come to the end of incl OR if the recursive call is true called with the tail of incl used as the second arg:

```
incl[:1] == '' or recurseString(full, incl[1:])    
#null check is first to prevent overflow
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a simple approach for this **without recursion**: create two sets with the strings you want and check if one set is inside the other one.

```
def contains(text, chars):
    textset = set(text)
    charset = set(chars)
    return charset.issubset(textset)

print contains("jackie", "ice") # True
print contains('jack','kcj') # True
print contains('stan','xun') # False
```

Comment: This isn't recursive. This may be a pointless question, but that doesn't mean this is the answer to that question.

Comment: Also, why `set(list(text))`? Any iterable that can be passed to `list` can also be passed straight to `set`. (Plus, `issubset` can take an iterable for its second argument.)

Comment: because this is NOT a recursive algorithm

Comment: aaaand you need to use recursive algorithm for this? Is there something wrong with pointing another solution for this problem? I think that's the idea of StackOverflow anyways, let's share ideias, not hate :)

Comment: have you looked at the question?

Comment: yes, and had you? "Right now I'm trying to use recursion of **a function** with **two parameters** to find **whether or not the second is included in the first**." Still looks good for me :)